# How to determine which measurements cause which?

Tags: python, causality

Suppose I have two sequences of measurements, $x_1[n]$ and $x_2[n]$ for $0 \le n \le N-1$.

How do I determine if there is a causal relationship between the two?

My first thought was, well... I can just find the correlation between $x_1$ and $x_2$.  But almost immediately I was struck by [**correlation is not causation**](https://www.theguardian.com/science/blog/2012/jan/06/correlation-causation).

OK, so in Python, we can generate  a uniform noise signal `x1` and then filter it to get `x2`.  Clearly, in this case, `x2` is causally related to `x1`.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as signal

Q = 50
N =1000
x1 = np.random.uniform(-1,1,N)
b,a = signal.iirfilter(1,[2*500*(1-1/(2*Q))/44100,2*500*(1+1/(2*Q))/44100])
x2 = signal.lfilter(b,a,noise1)
```

`x1`

[image: The noise signal x1.]

`x2`

[image: The filtered version of x1, x2.]

Unfortunately, the correlation of the two doesn't tell us much:

[image: Correlation of x1 and x2.]

Next, I thought about using [coherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_(signal_processing)):

$$
C_{x_1x_2}(\omega) = \frac{|G_{x_1x_2}(\omega)|^2}{G_{x_1x_1}(\omega) G_{x_2x_2}(\omega)}
$$

where $G_{ab}$ is the cross-spectral density between $a$ and $b$.

However, this just seems to tell me that the two are causally related... it doesn't tell me the direction of the causation.

[image: Coherences in both directions.]

The figure above shows what should be obvious: $C_{x_1x_2}(\omega) = C_{x_2x_1}(\omega)$.

So... how do I determine the direction of the causation?

---

For example, suppose I want to know whether $x_1$ caused $x_2$, or vice versa.

So either
$$
x_1 = h \star x_2
$$
or
$$
x_2 = g \star x_1
$$
where $\star$ is convolution, and $h$ and $g$ are the impulse responses of LTI systems. Presumably, $g$ is the inverse of $h$ so that $g \star h = 1$.

Is it possible that both $g$ and $h$ are stable and causal?

Comment: Is this even possible in general? If `x1 = x2 + 1`, you could say that `x2` came first and caused `x1`, or `x1` came first and caused `x2 = x1 - 1`. Maybe, if you can establish that `x1 = f(x2)` where `f` is non-invertible, then `x2` had to come first?

Comment: watching this. I could try to give a response, but I feel that there will be people better able to do.

Comment: @MBaz Right, but in your example there are no dynamics.  I'm wondering if one can make some assumptions about the dynamics relating the two measurements. See my update.

Comment: If $h$ introduces a delay, then $g$ would have to be acausal, right? (or vice versa).

Comment: OK, so I just estimate $g$ and $h$ and figure out which one is causal? Hmm.  Let me think.

Comment: @PeterK., were you able to make any progress on this problem?

Comment: @MBaz Not really!  I've read quite a bit.  [This *long* post by Michael Nielsen is quite interesting.](https://michaelnielsen.org/ddi/if-correlation-doesnt-imply-causation-then-what-does/)

Comment: @PeterK. Thanks for the update and the link!